# how to demonstrate python GIL (how do I know there is only one thread executing at a time)

Tags: python, gil

Is there any way to demonstrate 'only one thread can is executing code at a time'?

A strange observation is that I see multiple cores running in `htop`, as if there are multiple threads rea executing simultaneously, what is that?

(The reason why I want to do this, is that I'm using `pybind` to binding my cpp code to python, and I'm dealing with some GIL release policy, so I want see how many threads are executing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running some hard problem that uses lots of CPU, such as calculating the 15800000th term of the Fibonacci sequence. Takes around 2 seconds on a single thread using IDLE. Try doing it on two now.

```py
import threading
import timeit

def tesr():
    a, b = 1, 0
    for _ in range(15800000):
        a, b = a + b, b

# Current thread
print("Current thread time:")
print(timeit.timeit(
    stmt='tesr()',
    setup='from __main__ import tesr',
    number=1,
))
print()

# Single thread
print("Single thread time:")
print("(Should take about the same time as current)")
t = threading.Thread(target=tesr)
print(timeit.timeit(
    stmt='t.start(); t.join()',
    setup='from __main__ import t',
    number=1,
))
print()

# Two threads
t1, t2 = (threading.Thread(target=tesr) for _ in range(2))
print("Two threads time:")
print("(Should take about double the current / single time)")
print(timeit.timeit(
    stmt='t1.start(); t2.start(); t1.join(); t2.join()',
    setup='from __main__ import t1, t2',
    number=1,
))
```

My output:

```
Current thread time:
2.0613602900000387

Single thread time:
(Should take about the same time as current)
2.228870080999968

Two threads time:
(Should take about double the current / single time)
4.671865998000044
```